# Should a function be used in both static and object context

Tags: php, programming-languages

In my company's codebase, i see functions used in both static and object context. For e.g. a class A has a function b() which is called both using A::b() and/or object_of_type_A->b(). I know this throws an error if strict is turned on. But I wanted to know if this is a bad practice and if yes, then why? Thanks for any answers.

Let me know if I don't make sense anywhere. I would be happy to clarify.

Comment: If you code raises errors, fix them. Doesn't matter if you can get away with it by turning off E_STRICT. It's there, you know how to fix it, so fix it.

Comment: @gordon - the problem here is that the function is not defined as static, and does not use any class variables ($this). So, while I can go ahead and change all places to static/object, i need a clear reason to specify in the organization i work.. i hope the question makes more sense now.

Comment: It already made sense before :) But I think you should not have to explain to your company why you are fixing code that triggers errors, even if it is *just* E_STRICT. You see, PHP already tells you the should not be called this way, so why not just heed that. On a sidenote, if you are interested in improving code quality in your organization, have a look http://qualityassuranceinphpprojects.com/pages/tools.html

Comment: @gordon - thanks for the link, very nice indeed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some test code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

class Foo{
    public function a(){
    }
    public static function b(){
    }
}

$MyFoo = new Foo;
Foo::a(); // Strict Standards: Non-static method Foo::a() should not be called statically
Foo::b();
$MyFoo->a();
$MyFoo->b(); // No complaints

?>
```

PHP/5.3 warns about static calls to non-static methods, which is fine since they are subject to failure as soon as you want to access `$this`. But it does not complain about object context calls to static functions: there's nothing that can go wrong. [This behaviour is documented](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Declaring class properties or methods
>   as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of
>   the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an
>   instantiated class object (though a
>   static method can)
>   [...]
>   Because static methods are callable
>   without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable $this is
>   not available inside the method
>   declared as static.

So, as far as PHP is concerned, what you found in the code base is not wrong. However, I think it's slightly confusing.

Comment: +1, i think this is exactly what i was looking for... so, the behavior is correct but confusing :-)... is there any other reason to be concerned??? Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a php guy, but this sounds just like Java, where it's allowed but discouraged.

If it's static, I would *strongly* recommend only calling it in a static way. Otherwise it *looks* like it depends on the state of the object you're supposedly calling it on.

In Java the best example of this is `Thread.sleep()`. It's a static method which puts the *current thread* to sleep, always. But look at this code:

```
Thread t = new Thread(someTask);
t.start();
t.sleep(1000);
```

What does it *look* like that code is doing? It appears to be putting the *other* thread to sleep, whereas in fact it'll be the current thread that's sleeping. When you change it to a plain static call, it's more obvious:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

That doesn't refer to `t`, so *must* be about the current thread.

Unless there's something specific to php where calling the static method via a variable gives you some sort of polymorphism, I suggest you stick to calling it in the static way. The fact that strict mode tells you to do this is a pretty strong hint, IMO :)

Comment: there is no polymorphism involved. the function is called in both static as well object contexts. i am still not clear though if it is just best practice or any other issue is involved here. thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There is 'currently' no harm in using it either way except of course when called as a static function you can't access the $this member.

The reason it errors in strict is because not writing your code to strict standards can result in errors occurring due to a lack of diligence. in the future it may also cause your code to break. a static function has no $this member and it may break parameter passing.

Play it safe only call static functions with A::b() type calls.

DC

Comment: thanks for the answer. currently, it does not use $this inside the strict function.

Comment: A static member function cannot expect $this to be valid and therefore should never use the $this pointer. by way of comparison c++ has static members and non static members although it normally uses an implicit this pointer you can call the static member function using this->staticfunction() with no problems. but if you tried to use 'this' inside the static member function it would result in a compile time error because this is not valid in a static function

Answer (score 1):

Regarding accessing $this in a static function I found something a bit strange a while back (might be changed in later versions of PHP though, think I ran 5.2 or something).

You can read about it here but it's in swedish. But use google translate and it should be understandable.

http://www.phpportalen.net/viewtopic.php?p=560080#560080

Comment: I don't get the problem, even though he calls foo::getname() it is still called as a non static member and therefore $this points to a class type of 'foo' in the first call and 'bar' in the second, therefore the result he gets and calls weird is exactly what he should get.